# Problem with bibliography with the MITWPL style template

Tags: bibliographies, templates

I am embarrassed to ask this very specific question, but would be eternally grateful if somebody could kindly help.
I need to use a specific style template provided by a publisher (downloadable [here](http://mitwpl.mit.edu/publish/)), and am having a problem with it.
example.tex, which is included in the download, simply does not compile.
Below I attach the console messages I get when I try to compile it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I delete the last line of example.tex, `\custombib{\bibliography{example}}`, then a PDF without the bibliography can be generated, though still with warnings.
So, the problem obviously has to do with the bibliography.
However, I cannot even tell whether the provided style template or the example file is already flawed, or it is only in my environment (TeXShop 3.24 running on Mac OS 10.8.5) that this problem occurs.

Without fixing this problem, I cannot complete my paper with a bibliography.
I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Rather than showing pictures of the log file, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits the problem. Also point out where the `mitwpl` class can be found.

Comment: The MITWPL style template is found on [the website I linked in the above post](http://mitwpl.mit.edu/publish/). If you download the ZIP file, you can find the file named "example.text" in it.
Here is a shortened version that does not compile.  
`\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, dvips]{mitwpl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}
\begin{document}
\citep{MacFarlane:2005}
\custombib{\bibliography{example}}
\end{document}`

This can compile if `\custombib{\bibliography{example}}` is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `mitwpl.cls` is flawed. The definition of `\lingbib`, starting on line 245 contains `\newcommand{\bibfont}{#1}` which should be `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{#1}`. The command `\bibfont` is already defined in the package `natbib` that `mitwpl.cls` includes.

The example file `example.tex` is also flawed: ever section is labeled with the same `\label{sec:intro}` leading to a LaTeX warning of multiply defined labels. There are several warnings from the fancyhdr package that can be avoided with the command
`\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}` placed in the preamble.

Comment: This solved the problem. I cannot thank you enough! Thank you really!!